# Get list items that don't match most frequent value

Tags: python, python-collections

I have a list of dictionaries looking like this:

```
[{'customer': 'Charles', 'city': 'Paris'}, {'customer': 'John', 'city': 'New York'}, {'customer': 'Jean', 'city': 'Paris'}]
```

I tried something using collections which will return me the name of the most common city in this list of dictionaries:

```
city_counts = Counter(c['city'] for c in customers)
return city_counts .most_common(1)[0][0]
```

From this, I would like to return a list of all customers who are not in this city.
So, if I take the list I gave above, `['John']` should be the output.

I there a best way to do it ?

Comment: Can a customer be in multiple cities?

Comment: Don't limit the output of `most_common`, take the _last_ value?

Comment: `[c['customer'] for c in customers if c['city'] != most_common_city]`

Comment: Your title isn't the same as your question. Do you want the least frequent city, or do you want all the customers who aren't in the most frequent city?

Comment: @barmar, I want all the customers who aren't in the most frequent city

Comment: Please fix the title so you don't get wrong answers.

Comment: @barmar, I can't find any good one, if you have any, you are welcome to share

Comment: There you go, is that a good description?